# Error List indices must be intergers abut it works as long as i dont use input to get the argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have tried:

```
def funct(arg, list):
 Diferent_list=[]

 for i in arg:
     Diferent_list=Diferent_list+([list[1:][i][0:6]])
```

why does this works ?

```
funct((1,2,3),list)
```

but if i say:

```
arg= input((1,2,3))
funct(arg,list)
```

(inside input() i put what i put to test the prompt

it gives

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

thats why i need it to be (1,2,3) or any "tuple"

```
a = ['+'.join(s for s, _, _, _, _,_ in list), sum(x + y + z + c+v for _, x, y, z, c,v in distritos)
you can ignore that part
#, sum(q+w+e+r+t+y+u+i+o+p+a+s+d+f+g+h+j+k+l+ç for q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,ç in anotherlist)]
```

Comment: [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string. If you want a number you need to convert it.

Comment: yes, I get that but i converted the input ot everything i knew doesnt seem to matter intenger float list .... is there a way to get it "raw" (not has input tho) i mean literal what the user inputs

Comment: In Python 3.x input() always just returns what ever `str` the user types with the newline character removed at the end.  In Python 2.x input() actually parsed the user input string as a Python expression so if the user typed 2 + 2 it would return 4 as an `int`, if user typed (10, 20), if would return (10, 20) as a `tuple`, etc.
This was potentially very dangerous because the user could type in any arbitrary Python expression.  That being said you could get the same behavior in Python 3.x using arg = eval(input( )) but I would recommend against it!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

as noted in the comment from Mark Meyer, input() always returns a `str` in Python 3.x.  So modify your code to something like this to get a integer:

```
arg = int(arg)
```

Note however this can fail if they type in something that is not a number so if you want to be a little more robust then you should do the conversion inside a try: block and look for a `ValueError` exception indicating the conversion didn't work.  Finally you could wrap it in a `while` loop to let them keep trying until they finally put in an actual number! (the while loop may be overkill for your application in which case just print an error message and do sys.exit() if you get an Exception
)

```
import sys

while True:
    arg= input('(1,2,3, or q to quit) ')
    if arg == 'q':        # users just wants out, so sys.exit()
        sys.exit(0)
    try:
         arg = int(arg)
    except ValueError:    # int(arg) failed to convert
         print("bad number please try again")
    else:
         break            # NO exception occurred so number is good
                          # so break out of loop and move on
```

Comment: I get it but the problem is i wnat my input to be exacly (1,2,4) it cam be also (1,4,5) or just 1 but in this case it doesnt make sence for the user to make that because the main issue is i will edit post

Comment: Aha, I see, you can either use a tuple or a integer for input, sorry I missed that.
In that case you could try convert  your input into a `tuple` first and then if that fails try converting it into a `int` and use which ever one succeeds as your `arg` value

Answer (score 0):

```
eval() is the awnser
```

eg. eval(input("Put list you want to group here ( It needs to be in the form [a,b,c])"))

Comment: Found what i needed